# How to extract the holidays in iOS calendar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to extract the holidays from the iOS calendar?

I want to be able to read the events from the calendar and use them in my own calendar program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
// Get the appropriate calendar
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Create the start date components
NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1;
NSDate *oneDayAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents
                                              toDate:[NSDate date]
                                             options:0];

// Create the end date components
NSDateComponents *oneYearFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
oneYearFromNowComponents.year = 1;
NSDate *oneYearFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneYearFromNowComponents
                                                   toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                  options:0];

// Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneDayAgo
                                                        endDate:oneYearFromNow
                                                      calendars:nil];

// Fetch all events that match the predicate
NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 version

Get the user permission

```swift
func requestAccessToCalendar() {
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event, completion: {
        (accessGranted: Bool, error: Error?) in

        if accessGranted == true {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                getALLEvents
            })
        } else {

        }
    })
}

func getALLEvents(){
    let caledar = NSCalendar.current
    let oneDayAgoComponents = NSDateComponents.init()
    oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1
    let oneDayAgo = caledar.date(byAdding: oneDayAgoComponents as DateComponents, to: Date(), wrappingComponents: true)


    let oneYearFromNowComponents = NSDateComponents.init()
    oneYearFromNowComponents.year = 1
    let oneYearFromNow = caledar.date(byAdding: oneYearFromNowComponents as DateComponents, to: Date(), wrappingComponents: true)

    let store = EKEventStore.init()

    let predicate = store.predicateForEvents(withStart: oneDayAgo!, end: oneYearFromNow!, calendars: nil)

    let event = store.events(matching: predicate)
}
```